# Socket io on connection not connecting NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets

I just started learning `NodeJS` and I am trying to make a simple server-client project using `Socket io`.

What happens right now is that when I open `localhost:8001`, I don't see any logs inside the `listener.sockets.on` block.

```
var http = require('http');
var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('<h1>Hello!</h1>');
}).listen(8001);

var io = require('socket.io');
var listener = io.listen(app);

console.log("Sample Socket IO");

listener.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.emit('connected', 'Welcome');

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the logging will occur when a connection happens. You setup a listening socket, so try to connect to it. Try 'telnet 127.0.0.1 8001' to connect.

Comment: This might be a dumb question but running on the browser doesn't actually trigger the listener?

Comment: And telnet worked but it didn't give me the logs still

Comment: You can use the browser to initiate the connection. How are you running the server? Do you have a break point in the connection handler? Is there a log file?

Comment: I'm running what I have up there :(

Answer (score 0):

The browser page needs to load the socket.io client code for one thing.  That is the first thing missing that I can see.  Look through the example here http://socket.io/get-started/chat/ and make sure you are following exactly at first and then make changes after you get that example working.  Your server code looks a bit different from their example also.